# Replace specific text with a block of text

Tags: python, replace, readline

I am trying to replace a small section of text with a block of text. I am hoping that this block of text will be replaced using replace function of python. I would have really like to use `sed` to get this job, but I am on windows machine. Anyway here is my script, not sure why the block of text isn't being replaced.

```
# Change the current working directory to IDX location
import os
print os.getcwd()
os.chdir(##location of my text files##) 
print os.getcwd()

#Read file names

com_line=raw_input("File name please:")
contents=[]
strs = '#DREFIELD IDOL_SOURCE="idol source"\n#DREFIELD IDOL_TAXONOMY="taxonomy data"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_CATEGORY="IDOL_CATEGORY"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_PROMOTION="idol_promotion"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_PROMOTION_TERM="IDOL_PROMOTION_TERM"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_WHATSNEW="IDOL_WHATSNEW"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_SUMMARY="IDOL_SUMMARY"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_URL="IDOL_URL DATA"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_FORMNUMBER="IDOL_FORMNUMBER"\n #DREFIELD IDOL_DESCRIPTION="IDOL_DESCRIPTION DATA"\n#DRESECTION 0\n'
with open(com_line) as f:
     contents.append(f.readlines())
f.close

#Writing to file
f2 = open("test.idx", 'w')

for content in contents:
    for s in content:
        if s == '#DRESECTION 0\n':
            s.replace("#DRESECTION 0\n", strs)
        f2.write("%s" % s)
f2.close
```

I tested this code, and it is entering the conditional statement as well. Just wondering why is the needful text `#DRESECTION 0\n` not getting replaced with `strs` ? Also I am looking to do this operation of large text files worth few gigs. Is there a better way of reading large text files in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stings in Python are immutable. Once a string object has been created, it can't be modified. You can however create a new string based on the old one.

When you are calling `s.replace`, it doesn't modify `s` in place, because that's not possible. Instead, the `str.replace` method returns a new string. You could do `s = s.replace(...)` and it should work. However, there's no point in replacing the whole contents of one string with another string when you could just rebind the name to the new string.

I suggest using:

```
    if s == '#DRESECTION 0\n':
        s = strs
    f2.write(s)
```

I also changed the `write` call. There's no need to use string substitution here, since you want to write the whole string (and nothing extra). Just pass `s` as the argument.

There are a few other minor issues with your code:

For instance, you're not calling the `close` methods on your files, only naming them. You need `f2.close()` if you want to actually close the file. But you don't actually need to do that for `f`, since the `with` statement you're using will close the file automatically (you should probably use a `with` for `f2` and not bother with the manual `close` call).

There also doesn't seem to be much need `contents` to be a nested list (with just one item in the outer list). You probably want to do `contents = f.readlines()` rather than `append`ing the list of lines to an initially empty list. That will let you get rid of one of the loops in the later code.